Adding a node with different CPUs, Cores*Threadspercore to SLURM (Ex: i9-1300 having 8P+16E cores)
I am building a test cluster with nodes having i9-1300 processors. But I get an error saying the cores and CPUs doesn't match.
CPUs=32 match no Sockets, Sockets*CoresPerSocket or Sockets*CoresPerSocket*ThreadsPerCore

I tried changing the values, but i get error saying low socketcorethread count.
Is it possible to add such CPUs at all?
Any help is appreciated.

Try running slurmd -C on the node, this should print what slurm thinks the node has. That line can then be copy-pasted into slurm.conf.

Thank you for the quick response. The following is the output. But it didn't work.
NodeName=node001 CPUs=16 Boards=1 SocketsPerBoard=1 CoresPerSocket=8 ThreadsPerCore=2 RealMemory=63985

Slurm is not really yet designed for heterogenous CPU architectures. What you can do is configure Slurm to not check the hardware configure and just trust the information in the slurm.conf.
That is done with the config_overrides flag for the SlurmParameters option in slurm.conf.
